# Module name clash in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a module called Resume in the lib directory of my rails 3 app.

Now I also have a model called Resume which has 2 columns, name and version.

When I goto rails console and type the following to create a new Resume object from the model

```
> Resume.new(:name => "somename", :version => "someversion")
```

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Resume:Module
```

This error started only after I added the Resume module files to the lib directory. 
1. Is this a module name clash
2. How do I work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should namespace your module to avoid this kind of clashes:

```
module MyRailsApp
  module Resume
    ...
  end
end
```

and then, when you want to use the `Resume` module, use it like `MyRailsApp::Resume`.